# Is calling atoi without stdlib undefined behaviour?

Tags: c

Is calling `atoi` *without* including `stdlib.h` undefined behaviour?
I can't find where I have included `stdlib.h` in my project, even though I have used `atoi`.
The thing is actually `atoi` has been working fine - *it has been parsing integers correctly every time the software has been used*.
It is some embedded device.
So is there case this can be well defined?

---

btw. In this line:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#if __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif
#endif /* __cplusplus */
#include "sdkGlob.h"


#ifdef __cplusplus
#if __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

that header includes stdlib.h but I can't understand in which case it is included. And I am not sure if this cplusplus is defined anywhere. This is a c project anyway.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible to answer without seeing the contents of sdkGlob.h

Comment: *Undefined behavior* is a term to describe *language* behavior. It does not describe linker issues.

Comment: I don't know if it is UB, but you'll get warnings when using a function without including the header.

Comment: @Random832: sdkGlob.h includes stdlib - but is sdkGlob.h included itself? it is guarded with some ifdefs as you can see. So I ndeed asnwer assuming sdkGLob.h is not included, isn't it?

Comment: In what way is it guarded? The conditionals do not even embrace the include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to C99 it was acceptable to use functions that hadn't previously been declared. The compiler might generate a warning but there would be no error until the linker either didn't find the function or found a function of the same name with a signature other than the one that the compiler had guessed. Luckily for you, the compiler always guesses a return type of `int`.

In C99 it became necessary for function declarations to be visible but not all compilers strictly enforce the rule.

As per Random832's comment, it's also quite possible that `sdkGlob` simply includes `stdlib` for itself.

As to your other question: `sdkGlob` is always included but if run through a C++ compiler rather than a C compiler you also get the `extern "C"{ .. }` wrapping. That tells the C++ compiler not to mangle the names so that you can link against a version of that module that was built using an ordinary C compiler. It's the normal way to provide plain C libraries in a way that allows them to be used by both C and C++ code.

Comment: "As per Random832's comment, it's also quite possible that sdkGlob simply includes stdlib for itself" -- it does but that is what I asked, is the `sdkGlob` itself included? you can see it is guarded with some `ifdefs`

Comment: @User30015 Match each #if with an #endif - you should be able to tell that they are only surrounding the `extern "C" {` and `}`, not the include.

Comment: @Random832: I am not familiar with preprocessor macros. Like I said inside `"sdkGlob.h"`, indeed stdlib.h is included. So you say I have no issues then?

Comment: so you say it is included?

Comment: Yes, with its vanilla C signature, for both C and C++ targets. Ensuring the latter is what leads to the `#ifdef` parts.

Comment: So, are you saying that using a function without the necessary header is not UB on C89,C99 and C11?

Comment: @CoolGuy in C89, yes. In C99, no. In C89 the compiler will infer the argument types from the arguments you've supplied and assume an `int` return. C99 needs to have seen a prototype so must at least know the return type but will continue to infer the argument types. Which isn't always exactly perfect even when you're making valid calls as e.g. if you did `abs(<some float>)` then the compiler would incorrectly guess a `float` when what it wants to do is promote to a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

#### The short answer

Two possibilities:

- It's probable that `sdkGlob.h` include `stdlib.h` or define its own version of `atoi`.
- Some compilers, like GCC, resolve missing `#include` and even hide the errors or warnings. Run `gcc -Wall` and check if warnings appears.

#### About `ifndef`

The `#ifdef __cplusplus` sections are used by C++ compilers. Here, you're saying '*if and if only the code is being compiled by a C++ compiler, do ... *'.

The C-only version of your code:

```
#include "sdkGlob.h"
```

The C++-only version of your code:

```
extern "C"{
  #include "sdkGlob.h"
}
```